# Software GUI does not run locally but works if using SSH with X forwarding?

Tags: command-line, gnome, ssh, gui

The software I am trying to use is QualNet EDU 7.3. The GUI executable is located at `~/Scalable/qualnet-edu/7.3/bin/QualNetGUI`.

My Ubuntu is 14.04 LTS, using Linux kernel 3.13.0-44-generic.

If I simply type the executable path in my terminal, it says:

```
Unable to load library icui18n "Cannot load library icui18n: 
(libicui18n.so.48: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)" 
/home/<username>/Scalable/qualnet-edu/7.3/gui/lib/linux-x64/QualNetGUI: 
symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0: 
undefined symbol: g_type_add_instance_private
```

The first error doesn't seem serious. I believe it is the second error that defeated the GUI. I have searched for this problem, results show that the problem might be related to GNOME. However, I have tried reinstalling GNOME and related packages with `apt-get` but got no luck. I even tried to run this software in a GNOME desktop instead of my default Unity desktop, still no luck.

However if I do `ssh -X 127.0.0.1 ~/Scalable/qualnet-edu/7.3/bin/QualNetGUI` the GUI program runs, and I have not noticed any problem with this method so far.

I would like to know what is the cause of this strange phenomenon, and how to fix my system so the software GUI can run directly without using SSH X forwarding.

---

Update 10/05/2015:

This problem does not seem to be ubiquitous. The same problem did not happen on another newly installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS machine which runs kernel version 3.19.0-30-generic.

---

Update 10/19/2015:

The problem occurred on the machine I mentioned above now. The kernel version is still 3.19.0-30-generic. During these days I have installed some updates using `apt-get`. What I have also installed during these days are:

1. MATLAB R2010a for UNIX
2. A third-party Wi-Fi dongle driver

I don't know if they are related, I just listed them here in case.

Now I still need a solution or workaround to that problem.